# How to get camera movement when using openGL framebuffers

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have been writing a program to visualize a fractal point cloud and so far everything has been working, camera movement is using arc-ball movement centered on the origin and points are being rendered. However, I am needing to output the scene into an integrated window inside a UI so i have been trying to get frame buffers to work.

So far i have got a texture to be successfully rendered onto a quad that i am then outputting to the screen which for testing purposes is basically the same as when i was not using a fbo. My issue comes when trying to get camera movement to also display using the rendered texture. i know this is definitely possible as there are lots of examples of this but i haven't been able to get any to work with my code. I'm fairly certain my issue is with my shaders but i have scoured lots of websites, YouTube tutorials, openGL examples and found nothing that works. to the best of my knowledge i have to render the scene as normal so i have been using the same shaders that have worked for me previously for the initial rendering step but i have using my fbo instead of the default fbo

for simplicity's sake, i have just been rendering a point cube as it is faster than generating a fractal each time.

here is the main setup of the fbo, texture and rbo:

```
GLuint fbo;
GLuint texturebuffer;
GLuint rbo;
void initFBO(){
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    glGenTextures(1, &texturebuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); // once rbo memory allocated unbind
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
}
```

here is the main and the draw loop:

```
int main(){
    if(!setup())
        return -1;

    // // white background
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "new_vertex_shader", "new_fragment_shader" ); // custom shader
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("new_vertex_shader", "new_fragment_shader");
    GLuint modelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "model");
    GLuint viewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "view");    
    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

    GLuint quad_programID = LoadShaders( "screen_vertex_shader", "screen_fragment_shader" );
    GLuint textureID = glGetUniformLocation(quad_programID, "screenTexture");

    // initialise mvp matrices
    glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = perspective(radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(0,0,-RADIUS));
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 MVP;

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    GLfloat cube[24] = {
        0.5,0.5,0.5,
        0.5,-0.5,0.5,
        -0.5,0.5,0.5,
        -0.5,-0.5,0.5,
        0.5,0.5,-0.5,
        0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
        -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,
        -0.5,0.5,-0.5
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube),cube, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback);


    // ################# main draw loop #######################
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 ){

        // render to fbo first
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        computeMatricesFromInputs();
        ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
        ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
        ModelMatrix = getModelMatrix();
        MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);

        // render scene as normal
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer); // index buffer
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        glPointSize(POINT_SIZE);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, sizeof(cube));
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


        // bind back to default frame buffer to show on screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(quad_programID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(quad_vertex_buffer);

        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, sizeof(cube));
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main(){

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0);

}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Output data
out vec3 color;

void main(){

    // Output color = black 
    color = vec3(0,0,0);

}
```

screen quad vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

screen quad fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColour;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColour = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords);
}
```

sorry if this is quite a big block of code, im not entirely sure where the error would lie and im somewhat new to using openGL. many thanks in advance for anyhelp.

Comment: Why do you just draw `GL_POINTS` primitives? The 2nd pass has to render a screen space quad (e.g. 2 [`GL_TRIANGLES` primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)). What is `quad_vertex_buffer`? Why do you `glEnableVertexAttribArray` before `glBindVertexArray`? Note, `glEnableVertexAttribArray` changes a state in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

Comment: i have since changed the second pass to use `GL_TRIANGLES` and `quad_vertex_buffer` holds the the screen quad vertex array so i have renames it to `quadvao` which i think is more appropriate. i have now moved `glEnableVertexAttribArray` after `glBindVertexArray` but i still have the issue of no texture being shown onto the screen quad. I can try provide more information if possible but like i mentioned I'm mostly new to openGL so am not sure which order things need to be executed in.

Answer (score 0):

[`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) changes a state in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). It has to be done after binding the VAO by [`glBindVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml).
I assume that `quad_vertex_buffer` is a Vertex Array Object, even though the name "vertex_buffer" is misleading.

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(quad_vertex_buffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

When you draw the screen space quad (2nd pass), then you have to use a [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type which generates a (filled) polygon (probably `GL_TRIANGLES` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`), rather than the point primitive type `GL_POINTS`:

<s>`glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, sizeof(cube));`</s>

```py
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, sizeof(cube))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but when i use GL_TRIANGLES or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP on the second pass, instead of just getting the points of the rendered cube, which is what im looking for, i of course get a rectangle. i still have the issue of camera movements not being applied too.

Comment: @SuperSpudDude The camera movment is applied to the points in the 1st pass. But note `MVP` is never changed, It's constant.